# Ruby Infinite While Loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, infinite-loop

My goal is to take each element in multidimensional array, create 12 copies that will be processed (without changing the original value), append the processed values to the array, and repeat if necessary to meet the total number of desired values:

```
total = 4
arr = Array.new(1) { Array.new(3, 127.5) }

while arr.count < total
  tmp = arr

  tmp.each do |item|
    new_arr = Array.new(12, item)
    #processing the 12 arrays I just created would happen here
    arr.concat new_arr
    puts arr.count 
  end 
end
```

This portion of the code creates an infinite loop.  I can not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on assigning `tmp` with `arr`. They are the same object as you can see here:

```
> arr = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
> tmp = arr
=> [1, 2, 3]
> arr.concat([4,5,6])
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> tmp
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You'd need to make a copy of the array by using `dup` or `clone` pending on your needs

if you do `tmp = arr.dup` it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` and `tmp` are the same object. While adding to `arr` , `tmp` grows, so there are new subarrays for `tmp.each` to process.

Answer (score 0):

Your infinite loop is happening because you're adding items to the array in a second loop inside it, so subsequent iterations are acting on the previously added entries. Also, you are not making a copy of arr when you do 'tmp = arr', you are setting a reference.  Check this out and see if it helps:

```
> arr = ['test','test1','test2']
=> ["test", "test1", "test2"]
> tmp = arr
=> ["test", "test1", "test2"]
> arr << 'test3'
=> ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3"]
> tmp
=> ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3"]
> tmp = arr.dup
=> ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3"]
> arr << 'test3'
=> ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test3"]
> tmp
=> ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

With that in mind, maybe you could try something like:

```
total = 4
original_arr = Array.new(1) { Array.new(3, 127.5)}
new_arr = []
total.times do |i|
  original_arr.each do |v|
    new_arr << Array.new(12, v)
    puts i
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

just use

```
arr += new_arr
```

instead of

```
arr.concat new_arr
```

Comment: providing the answer help, but answering why is creating a infinite loop will make it much better

Comment: Then you're not answering the question

Comment: The questioned was already marked as answered and I don't have enough points to comment..